# Why this Java Script POST not Working?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp-classic

```
<script language="javascript">
 function storemarker() {
     var txtTitle = document.getElementById('txtTitle').value;

     var sendInfo = { txtTitle: txtTitle

     };

     var req;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else {
         req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE
     }
     req.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
             var mydata = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
         }
     }
     req.open("POST", "Home.aspx/ButtonClick", true);
     req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     req.send("txtTitle=" + txtTitle );
 }
```

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="buttom" value="Add Road" onclick="storemarker()"/> 

[WebMethod]
    public static string ButtonClick(string txtTitle)
    {
        //return title;
        return "alert('The Button was Clicked');";
    }
```

I am trying to implement this as a small example. I just reviewed the code I can't see whats wrong.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code? Thanks

Comment: **HOW** is this not working?

Comment: what are you expecting it to do? You don't do anything with the response

Comment: Consider listening to the `submit` event and preventing the default action of the event using `event.preventDefault` method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cancel the default behavior of the submit button which is, well, submitting the form, or use plain button and not submit button.

As it stands now, your code does send request to the server, but then also submits the form hence the page "reloads".

One of these would work:

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="buttom" value="Add Road" onclick="storemarker(); return false;"/>
```

Or:

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="buttom" onclick="storemarker()">Add Road</button>
```